# Show bottom sheet do not appear

Tags: flutter, dart

> I have a button called new_list at the bottom of my column widget to show bottom sheet but when i clicked on it the bottom sheet do not appear and the app bar moving right causing rendering error to appear i can not understand this error why it do not appear and why app bar moving when clicked the button.
> it is the first time happened i used it before but it did not do that.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:practice_projects/todo/shared/components/components.dart';
import 'package:practice_projects/todo/shared/cubit/cubit.dart';
import 'package:practice_projects/todo/shared/cubit/state.dart';

class ListsHomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {

final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

final listNameController = TextEditingController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return BlocConsumer<TodoCubit, TodoStates>(
  listener: (context, state) {},
  builder: (context, state) {
    var cubit = TodoCubit.get(context);
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        backwardsCompatibility: false,
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarColor: Colors.white
        ),
        title: Row(
          children: [
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 25,
              backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                'assets/images/mee.jpg'
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 20,),
            Text(
              'Mohamed Harby',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.purpleAccent
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        titleSpacing: 10,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.purpleAccent,
            ),
            onPressed: () {

            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          addList(
            listName: 'My Day',
            iconData: Icons.wb_sunny_outlined,
            iconColor: Colors.yellow
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          addList(
            listName: 'Important',
            iconData: Icons.star_border
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          addList(
            listName: 'To-Do',
            iconData: Icons.menu,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          addList(
            listName: 'Groceries',
            iconData: Icons.local_grocery_store_outlined,
            iconColor: Colors.green,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          addList(
            listName: 'Home',
            iconData: Icons.home_outlined,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          addList(
            listName: 'Travel',
            iconData: Icons.airplanemode_active_sharp,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          addList(
            listName: 'Work',
            iconData: Icons.work,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: InkWell(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    size: 35,
                    color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10,),
                  Text(
                    'New List',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              onTap: () {
                if(cubit.addListBoolean) {
                  scaffoldKey.currentState.showBottomSheet((context) => Form(
                    key: formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: listNameController,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          validator: (String value) {
                            if(value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'list title can not be empty';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ));
                  cubit.toggleList();
                } else {
                  cubit.toggleList();
                  //Navigator.pop(context);
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

}
}

Comment: Does it work when no `if` is present?

Comment: yes it works well when no if exist

Comment: Then there's a problem in the condition of the if. Try using a debugger.

Comment: is it ok `cubit` or `bloc` if we just use  `showBottomSheet( context: context,builder)`  ?

Comment: no i tried this but the errors is same